# A problem on Euclidean Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How can i prove that if a triangle has sides of lengths a, b, e, then its area
S satisfies the inequality
$$4\sqrt{3}\leq a^{2}+b^{2}+ c^{2}$$

with equality holding only for equilateral triangles. (Hint: If $\theta$ is the angle between sides $b$ and $c$, chosen so that it is at most $60$, then use the formulas
$$2S= b c \sin \theta$$
$$2b c \cos \theta= b^{2} + c^{2} - a^{2}$$
$$\cos (60 - \theta) = \dfrac{(\cos \theta)+ \sqrt{3}\sin \theta}{2}$$
Thanks

Comment: This is called [Weitzenböck's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\cot{A}=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{4S}\implies{}\sum_{\text{cyc}}\cot{A}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4S}.$$

Hence by Jensen's Inequality for $f(x)=\cot{x}$ we have,

$$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4S}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\cot{A}\ge{}\sqrt{3}.$$

Equality occurs iff $\angle{A}=\angle{B}=\angle{C}=60\implies{}a=b=c.$